# Hyperledger-Composer: How to build transaction processor function issuing identity for participant?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have built a hyperledger-composer application (angular front-end, connecting to composer-rest-server), from which, so far, authentication is missing.

I have some difficulties trying to figure out how authentication can be implemented.

Even the very first step isn't working. The first step in implementing authentication is, as I understand from the docs, to issue an identity for each participant in the network.

I have created a minimal example, which illustrates the problem I currently have.

Here is the model.cto file of this minimal example network:

```
namespace org.comp.network


participant SampleParticipant identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

transaction IssueID {
  --> SampleParticipant participant
  o String identity
}
```

And this is the logic.js file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Sample transaction
 * @param {org.comp.network.IssueID} issueID
 * @transaction
 */
async function issueID(tx) {


   let ID = tx.participant.participantId;

   let p = 'org.comp.network.SampleParticipant#' + ID;

   let IDENTITY = tx.identity;

   await issueIdentity(p, IDENTITY);

}
```

The function "issueIdentity" is supposed to issue an identity for a given participant (see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue.html)

However, when submitting the transaction "issueID", I get the following error message:

[image]

Apparently, the function "issueIdentity" is not "known" (although it is used here in the docs: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue)

How can I build a transaction processor function that issues an identity for a participant in my network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations on your example above ...

The ReferenceError you have is because the parameter you define with the `@param` decoraror is **issueID**, but the one you declare for your function is **tx**.  If you change the decorator line to be:

`* @param {org.comp.network.IssueID} tx`

then the ReferenceError will be solved.

The second issue I see is that the Runtime API (which is what the Transaction uses) does not include issueIdentity method.
**issueIdentity** is a method of the **BusinessNetworkConnection** class  which is part of the Client Api not the Runtime API.

In order to Issue Identities (to an existing participant) you you can't use Transaction logic,  you will need to write a separate Javascript API program, or use the REST API or the Command Line.